# Receiving a forEach error when requiring and running a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am recreating my Discord Bot and currently have this code, however, I am receiving an error in which I do not understand on what is throwing it, as it has worked previously before the adding of the new Object. The files are there, I require them properly, but it keeps throwing the error.

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ fetchAllMembers: true });
const { token } = require('./../JSON/config.json');

const bot = {
  client: client,
  commands: new Map(),
  aliases: new Map(),
  options: {
    productionMode: true,
    testingMode: false
  },
  login: function() {
    return client.login("token-here");
  },
  scoutPrefix: "^",
  devPrefix: "$",
  staff: [ "id-here" ],
}

[ 'commandHandler', 'eventHandler' ].forEach(h => require(`./Handlers/${h}`)(scout))

bot.login();
//client.login(token);
```

```js
C:\Users\PC\Documents\Files\Development\Staff Bots\Alpha\Core\core.js:24
[ 'commandHandler', 'eventHandler' ].forEach(h => require(`./Handlers/${h}`)(scout))
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Documents\Files\Development\Staff Bots\Alpha\Core\core.js:24:38)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it interpreted as

```js
const bot = {
  // ...
}['commandHandler', 'eventHandler'].forEach(...)
```

To fix the problem, add a semicolon to prevent ambiguity.

```js
const bot = {
  // ...
}; // <<

['commandHandler', 'eventHandler'].forEach(...);
```